# ARCORE in Redmi Note 4

Tags: android, arcore

I am developing small augmented reality apps and using REDMI NOTE 4 mobile for this purpose.

While running program I'm getting the following issue:

> This application requires the latest version of ARCore

When I go to Google Play to install it, it is saying that

> Your device isn't compatible with this version.

Is there any way to run my app?

Answer (score 1):

see [supported devices](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices) - the [REDMI NOTE 4](https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_redmi_note_4-8531.php) is not listed there.

probably it would be supported, once it had been updated to Oreo.

because the list tells for many devices:

> Requires Android 8.0 or later

Comment: Any other hack to install it? I  need to develop as part of my project and I cant buy a new mobile for that.

Comment: @hanugm you could build your own Android 8.0... or go for a budget device. recently got me the MotoX4, which meanwhile is at 200€ only and which is quite good for that price (and it's supported for certain). unless REDMI would provide ARM64 drivers, getting another device or waiting for an update are the only options available.

Comment: Okay, I will try for rooting method (many Youtube videos are showing). I will try them once, if possible, it would be a great help for me.

Comment: @hanugm rooting does not change the OS... you need to build AOSP from source, with 64bit drivers - in case Xiaomi would provide them (else you have no chance). custom ROM != root... an unlocked boot-loader is required to flash it.

Comment: @hanugm this may be a religion, unless it's running Oreo (could imagine it to work on such devices). just read the comments there. when the system API are not present, it does not help if one manages to install ARcore.

Comment: try this ROM: https://download.pixelexperience.org/santoni (hereby I disclaim the liability for suggesting that). because faking the build properties in best case permits the install, but it won't function. the fake build properties might still be required to install from the Play Store.